The logs on browser shows that components are rendering multiple times
So here is the code for weathercard.jsx and when it loads up and when i check the logs the components are rendering multiple times
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import HighlightText from "./utility/HighlighText";
import { weatherData } from "./test";

const WeatherCard = memo(({ arrow, title, routeCard, text, flightDetails }) => {
  const [toggleCard, setToggleCard] = useState(false);

  const weatherDataAtis = weatherData["d-atis"];
  const metar = flightDetails.metar;
  const taf = flightDetails.taf;
  const datis = flightDetails.datis;

  const coloredText = HighlightText({
    text: weatherDataAtis.dataString,
    highlightedPhrases: weatherDataAtis.highlight,
  });

  const handleToggleCard = () => {
    setToggleCard((prev) => !prev);
  };

  if (routeCard)
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <h3 className="card__title">
          {arrow ? "▼" : null} {title}
          <NavLink
            to="https://skyvector.com/?fpl=%20KEWR%20LANNA%20J48%20CSN%20FANPO%20Q40%20AEX%20DOOBI2%20KIAH"
            className="card__route__link"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Show on SkyVector Map
          </NavLink>
        </h3>
        <div className="card__route">
          <div className="card__route__text">{text}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  if (weatherData) {
    const { METAR, TAF, D_ATIS, name } = flightDetails || {};
    return (
      <>
        <h3 className="weather__title">
          <span>Weather for </span> {name}
        </h3>

        <div className="card">
          <div>
            <div className="card__depature__subtitle card__header--dark">
              <h3 className="card__depature__subtitle__title">D-ATIS </h3>
              <span className="card__depature__time">34 mins ago</span>
            </div>
            <div className="card__depature__details">
              <p>{datis}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="card__depature__subtitle  card__header--dark">
              <h3 className="card__depature__subtitle__title">METAR</h3>
              <span className="card__depature__time">34 mins ago</span>
            </div>
            <div className="card__depature__details">
              <p>{metar}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="card__depature__subtitle  card__header--dark">
              <h3 className="card__depature__subtitle__title">TAF</h3>
              <span className="card__depature__time">166 mins ago</span>
            </div>
            <div className="card__depature__details">
              <p>{taf}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h3 className="card__title" onClick={handleToggleCard}>
        {arrow ? "▼" : null} {title}
      </h3>

      <div className={toggleCard ? null : "card__body"}>
        <div className="card__depature__subtitle">
          <h3 className="card__depature__subtitle__title">D-ATIS </h3>
          <span className="card__depature__time">34 mins ago</span>
        </div>
        <div className="card__depature__details">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div className="card__depature__subtitle">
          <h3 className="card__depature__subtitle__title">METAR</h3>
          <span className="card__depature__time">34 mins ago</span>
        </div>
        <div className="card__depature__details">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div className="card__depature__subtitle">
          <h3 className="card__depature__subtitle__title">TAF</h3>
          <span className="card__depature__time">166 mins ago</span>
        </div>
        <div className="card__depature__details">
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

export default WeatherCard;


This is the logs
searchValue in Details.jsx {value: 'Newark Liberty International Airport (EWR)', label: 'Newark Liberty International Airport (EWR)', name: 'Newark Liberty International Airport', code: 'EWR', id: '66176711170d1d57a24dfb23'}
Details.jsx:19 searchValue in Details.jsx {value: 'Newark Liberty International Airport (EWR)', label: 'Newark Liberty International Airport (EWR)', name: 'Newark Liberty International Airport', code: 'EWR', id: '66176711170d1d57a24dfb23'}
Details.jsx:32 res.data from Details.jsx {metar: 'KEWR 281751Z 27008G24KT 10SM FEW045 FEW130 SCT180 …993 RMK AO2 SLP136 T03280211 10333 20244 56013 $\n', taf: 'KEWR 291732Z 2918/3024 09007KT P6SM SCT030 BKN040 …P6SM SCT025 BKN050 \n  PROB30 3018/3024 6SM -SHRA\n', datis: 'EWR ATIS INFO C 1751Z. 07005KT 10SM OVC032 26/17 A…CTIONS AND ASSIGNED ALT. ...ADVS YOU HAVE INFO C.'}
Details.jsx:32 res.data from Details.jsx {metar: 'KEWR 281751Z 27008G24KT 10SM FEW045 FEW130 SCT180 …993 RMK AO2 SLP136 T03280211 10333 20244 56013 $\n', taf: 'KEWR 291732Z 2918/3024 09007KT P6SM SCT030 BKN040 …P6SM SCT025 BKN050 \n  PROB30 3018/3024 6SM -SHRA\n', datis: 'EWR ATIS INFO C 1751Z. 07005KT 10SM OVC032 26/17 A…CTIONS AND ASSIGNED ALT. ...ADVS YOU HAVE INFO C.'}
I will attach screenshot as well enter image description here
Why are the components rendering multiple times, does it have anything to with use effect or does the javascript loads up differently in production and development environment ?

The code you've pasted has no console.log()s whatsoever – how on earth does something appear in the console?

Anyway – React is at liberty to call your component function as many times as it likes, so putting console.log()s into component bodies will make you chase red herrings. It doesn't mean that the DOM gets updated multiple times.

So it doesn’t put any load on any backend or servers if it is logging components multiple times?

Sorry I am really new to programming

See your browser's Network inspector tab to see what backend calls are being made.
